# Hoverintent working in jquery1.8.3 but not in 1.9.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was working with the accordion from the jquery-ui website, but even the simple demo wasn't working for me. I traced the error to the hoverintent not being supported with jquery-1.9.1.js but works in 1.8.3.js.

You can copy the script (view source) available here, http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent. Change it to this,

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and it will stop working.

Any suggestions on how I should fix it? All the other part of my code are compatible with jquery-1.9.1.js.

Comment: It may be because jQuery UI is compatible with 1.9.0 and hasn't been ironed out with 1.9.1.

Comment: The Hoverintent event is not something added by jQuery UI, it's just an example that was defined on that page. If you want to use it, you're going to have to update it yourself to work in the latest version.

Comment: @KevinB: +1, I never thought of the code being only sample code so I ensured to update the wording on my answer to make it clear it is not jQuery UI owned code but as you said, example code. Don't want anyone to start thinking that jQuery UI is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing code in jQuery 1.9.x please also use migrate-js.

A lot of deprecated features have been removed in 1.9.x and the migrate-js contains the removed features and shows you what they are through console messages.

In your case it is as per migrate-js message, it seems that hoverintent is using a removed feature:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated
```

Adding the migrate-js file reference in addition to 1.9.x makes it work again.

However, as mentioned by [**Kevin B**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) in the comment on the original post, the code is an example so you either need to upgrade the code yourself or keep the migrate-js file reference in your application, which is not recommended as a permanent solution though.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LYL3/) - Using 1.9.1 + migrate-js for Hoverintent

---

---

#### Useful Resources for 1.9.x

---

- [**jQuery 1.9.1 Release Notes**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/)
- [**jQuery Migrate 1.1.0 Released**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/)
- [**jQuery 1.9 RC1 and Migrate RC1 Released**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/09/jquery-1-9-rc1-and-migrate-rc1-released/)

There is more on their blog which are a very good read

Comment: Basically adding the migrate-js file does the trick - <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"> .....Thanks again. I am just starting out with this project. Should I be continuing with jquery 1.9+ , or should I go back to jquery 1.8.3?...Thanks anyways

Comment: @PratikBothra: If it is a new project use the latest if you can. Off course, the rest is situational. If you like to use the code from the UI example that won't work unless you re-write it, use the migrate-js file or use 1.8.3. I would try to go for either re-write and use 1.9.1 or use 1.8.3 as using migrate-js is suppose to only be a temp solution to help you upgrade/migrate your code or let you use jQuery plug-ins your code depends on until the authors upgraded them to be compatible with 1.9.x.